# error: RPC failed; result=55, HTTP code = 0 Increased buffer no success

Tags: git, github

When trying to push a commit to github, it just hangs at "Total 7 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)" for quite some time, then gives me the following error:

```
error: RPC failed; result=55, HTTP code = 0
```

I've tried increasing the http buffer size to 500MB, but no luck.

Edit: the GitHub windows client also says "Binary files differ" about the files i'm trying to upload.

Comment: I've already said, increasing the http buffer size didn't help.

Comment: Just linking this as related, for future visitors: [Push to GitHub error: Couldn't find host github.com in the .netrc file; using defaults](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2949128/456814).

Comment: Related: [Git push error: RPC failed; result=55, HTTP code = 0](http://michelelepri.blogspot.com/2012/10/git-push-error-rpc-failed-result55-http.html).

Answer (score 1):

After a short code-dive i come along with the following findings.
The `result` code is generated by `libcurl`.

The definition in the [`libcurl-errors`](https://github.com/bagder/curl/blob/19122c07682c268c2383218f62e09c3d24a41e76/docs/libcurl/libcurl-errors.3) states:

```
.IP "CURLE_SEND_ERROR (55)"
Failed sending network data.
```

According to the [use of the corresonding `CURLE_SEND_ERROR`-constant](https://github.com/bagder/curl/search?q=CURLE_SEND_ERROR&type=Code) there are many reasons why this may happen. Since curl is often used and seems to be a well known library i would suggest the bug is based wether on the github-client or on the networkside (due to a proxy-environment f.e.).

In addition to this [SO-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437642/git-efrror-rpc-failed-result-55-http-code-0-on-push?rq=1) i'd like to recommend you trying the following steps to localize the bug:

- Install [msysGit](http://msysgit.github.io/), configure it properly and invoke `env GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git push` in your working directory. Then let's see where curl hangs.
- Or try your push with a different git-gui (like [Sourcetree](http://sourcetreeapp.com/)) and with the git cli. If the bug disappears write to support@github.com and tell them about your findings.